# How do I include this byte in my byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

I'm on Windows 10. I am using Visual Studio 2019. Language C#

I am trying to include this byte into my byte array, but it just gives me an error.

Please help.

```
byte[] mybyte = new byte[] { 74, 68, 69, 73, 69, 73, 5F, 73, 65, 63, 72, 65, 74, 61, 73, 64, 06, 00, 00, 00 };
```

The one I am trying to include is **5F**, but it gives me an error when I try to include it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals

Comment: @madreflection
do i just need to add 0x to all of the numbers?

Comment: It would appear so. The first four bytes, if prefixed with `0x`, would form "this" in ASCII or UTF-8. Without it, it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help madreflection

The fix was to add 0x to the start of the bytes.